# Reviewer Stats/Editor Stats links now point to nowhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, review

[Link](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7498). Screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot of links that used to work but no longer do]

It used to be that these links would take me to a list of those people's reviews/edits. They no longer do. Both links point to `/review/suggested-edits/ProfileLink` [sic, not a placeholder].

Same on SO (and I suppose all other sites), see for yourself e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/683606).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy, which should happen in about 1/2 an hour.

Basically a missing sigil messed up the link generation there, that's all.

Comment: [It's merely a flesh wound!](http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/4900000/Just-A-Flesh-Wound-monty-python-and-the-holy-grail-4964886-800-450.jpg)